# What does ??? mean in Swift

Tags: swift, null, option-type

I know of the `??` but I'm seeing `???` in my code

That is:

```
request.parameters = [

                "start_coords"  :   "\(startCoords?.latitude ??? ""),\(startCoords?.longitude ??? "")",
                "end_coords"    :   "\(endCoords?.latitude ??? ""),\(endCoords?.longitude ??? "")",

            ]
```

`startCoords` and `endCoords` both have type `CLLocationCoordinate2D?`

Basically what I want this code to do is if `startCoords` is `nil` have `"start_coords"`  correspond to an empty string `""`. And I want the same for `endCoords`.

Does this code do that with `???`?

Comment: That's not defined by the standard library. Search your project for an `infix operator ???` declaration.

Comment: It's probably this: https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/optionals-string-interpolation/

Comment: ah okay i see. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

??? Is not a swift operator, could be an extension that was defined somewhere in your code or a third party code.